# Custom filtering on YouTube content

Tags: youtube

I want to impose some restrictions on YouTube for my 5 year old son. It's not about sexual, aggressive or violent content, that's pretty much covered by the SafeSearch filter and frankly, I don't care that much if my son sees a naked person once in a while, I guess he'll live... It's about some users providing hours and hours of toy advertisements, which my kid keeps stumbling upon and in my opinion gives him wrong impressions (do some of you know leokimvideo, it's true sad!)

Approaches I have considered:

- blocking the content of specific users from within youtube - impossible as far as I know
- filtering specific urls on my squid proxy - impossible because YouTube requires the use of tls/https nowadays, which makes inspection / filtering impossible.
- block port 443 - won't work youtube ceases to work altogether

So, any clue for a solution?

Comment: Maybe running a persistant sslstrip "server" can help?

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be a good approach, but I am afraid the youtube APP will check the validity of the certificate and refuse to work with an alternate certificate.

Comment: Same question (IMO): I let my 5 year old go into the local bar unattended, how can I prevent just the "bad people" talking to him or offering a drink?  Damn bars! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There exist extensions you can use that can block certain channels from ever popping up on YouTube, I believe it's called Video Blocker.

Using a mobile device and installing the [YouTube Kids app](http://kids.youtube.com) would also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered same problem, had just to create my own android app for that purpose. Its a simple youtube viewer that only shows videos from a predefined set of channels. Looks like original viewer, but instead of recommended list to the right it has a list of random videos from selected channels.

This allows me to select only channels with good content for my son and be sure that he will not open one of these weird ugly 'child' videos by clicking the 'recommended' items.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.sundogs.youtubekiosk